# Magento2 - Checkout session returning empty if cache is enabled issue

Tags: magento2, session

I am setting the `custom checkout session` value in `controller` and I am not getting that value in `view model.`

If `cache` is disable I am getting the get the `session` value but If `cache` is enabled If returning empty value.

Is anyone having any idea on this?

Comment: Can you share the piece of code which you are using to set the session and also share the file path where that code is placed.

Comment: @ArbabAhmed setting the id in controller as following.
$ecp =1;
$this->checkoutSession->setVal($ecp);
getting it in view model file as
this->checkoutSession->getVal();

also Injecting the decencies in constructor for checkout session.

Only issue is when i disable the cache, I am able to get the value.